# The list of list math operation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 1000 files and by using Scipy I can have the peak points for each of my files which you can see a template of points below:

```
[[4   29   73  111  130  140  167  231  248  267  284  298  320  333
   379  404  1299 1311 1326 1337 1372 1409 1426 1437 1511 1549 1578 1591 1604 1646]]
```

After getting the peaks coordinate, I want to have an operation (math operation) on the points and I need to have the distance between two consecutive points then plotting the results. The code which I have written is below but I got the error of indexing.

```
import numpy
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

Files = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in Files])
FILES= ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]
gg = []
my_l_h = []

for i, d in enumerate(FILES):
    a = np.loadtxt(d).T
    x = a[3]
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=10)

    gg = [peaks]

    L_h = np.array(gg)
for numbers in L_h:
    jp = L_h[:,numbers]-L_h[:,numbers-1]
    my_l_h.append(jp)
    print(my_l_h)
t = np.arange(0,len(my_l_h)
plt.plot(t, my_l_h)
```

The error that I have gotten is below:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-825708f0445f> in <module>
     15     #print(L_h)
     16     for numbers in L_h:
---> 17         jp = L_h[:,numbers]-L_h[:,numbers-1]
     18         my_l_h.append(jp)
     19         print(my_l_h)

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Your code seems far from minimal and is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MichaelButscher I edited the question based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with `i`:

```py
for i, d in enumerate(FILES):
    ...
    L_h = ...

for numbers in L_h:
    jp = L_h[:,i]-L_h[:,i-1]
    ...
```

Thus, there is no link between L_h size and your also not using `numbers`. I'm guessing it should be something like `jp = L_h[numbers]-L_h[numbers-1]`. Also it's strange that `L_h` values from the first loop are not remembered. When you go into second loop, you have only `L_h` from last file.

Maybe you want to do something like:

```py
L_h = []
for i, d in enumerate(FILES):
    ...
    L_h.append(np.array([peaks]))
L_h = np.array(L_h)
for numbers in L_h:
    jp = L_h[:,numbers]-L_h[:,numbers-1]
    ...
```

Comment: the first thing that you mentioned, I did like yours but it showed up `too many indices for array` . And the second one, you mean in the first loop I did not define `L_h`?

Comment: Ok, my suggestion is corrected. You're defining `L_h` but then overwriting it constantly. When you exit the first loop, you only have last value.

Comment: Apparently, there is an error of  `too many indices for array` and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: See my suggestion between blocks of code (it was edited) and the second block of code. Have you tried them? If so, then which doesn't work?

Comment: yes, of course, I have tried the second block which has been corrected but there is still a problem of too many indices

Comment: Can you tell what is `L_h.shape` after `L_h = np.array(L_h)` ?

Comment: the shape after applying numpy.array(L_h) is `2709`

Comment: It's seems you're not using the first three `L_h` commands I've provided. For reference: `np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])]).shape` returns `(2, 2)`.

Comment: I think you're not fully using the code I've provided. You may want to update your original post to show current code and current traceback. In any case, [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is best.